# Manipulação e Tratamento de Erro

Tags: php

Quero saber como deve ser feito o tratamento de erro, corretamente, para uma variável não obrigatória, uma vez que caso ela não seja informada, é gerado um `Fatal Error - Undefined Index`.

**Contexto**:

Através do meu sistema eu cadastro uma publicação(documentos para o usuário visualizar), e crio um sistema de pastas para o usuário acessar os dados posteriormente.

**Problema**:

Quando um publicante vai cadastrar a publicação, ele pode informar todos os campos ou alguns(no caso a minha dúvida é especificamente, sobre os campos `fk_empregado` e `mes` ), que quando há o cadastro de dados e não é informado `fk_empregado` ou o campo `mes` ele gera a seguinte `Notice`:

```
Notice: Undefined index: fk_empregado in ... on line 14 //Linha que recebe através de POST os dados do campo empregado
Notice: Undefined index: mes in ... on line 19 //Linha que recebe através de POST os dados do campo mes
```

Então, fica minha pergunta, **exatamente como eu posso informar ao script que não tem problema esses dois campos estarem indefinidos, e que ele pode continuar normalmente**(não sei a resposta, mas tenho certeza que não é com o `@`)?

Código da Página InserirPublicacao.php :

```
    $fk_titulo = $_POST['publicacao'];
    $fk_tipo = $_POST['tipo_publicacao'];
    $fk_empregado = $_POST['empregado'];  
    $fk_empresa = $_POST['empresa_destino'];
    $data_vencimento = $_POST['data_vencimento'];
    $data_pagamento = $_POST['data_pagamento'];
    $arqName = $_FILES['arquivo']['name']; 
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $ano = $_POST['ano'];
    $valor = $_POST['valor'];
    $publicante = $_SESSION['nome'];
    $observacao = $_POST['observacao'];
    $status = "N";

    $dir = 'upload/publicacoes/' . implode('/', array_filter([$fk_empresa, $fk_tipo, $fk_titulo, $fk_empregado, $ano, $mes]))."/";
```

Comment: Você pode mandar elas sem ter nenhum valor, assim creio que não dá erro (não conheço muito bem o comportamento do PHP)

Comment: Quando elas são recebidas vazias é gerado um Notice Undefined Index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O primeiro ponto é você realmente precisa dessas atribuições? não pode usar o `$_POST` direto? Se não puder as duas melhores formas de testar a existência de uma chave são.

#### 1) `isset()`/`empty()` mais o uso do ternário

Basicamente o `isset()/empty()` verificam a existência (conforme seus critérios) caso sim `$idade` recebe o valor do array do contário recebe um valor padrão, no caso 99.

```
$arr = array('nome' => 'abc', 'email' => 'abc@abc.com');
$idade = !isset($arr['idade']) ? $arr['idade'] : 99;
```

#### 2) Uso do operador null coalescing (`??`) disponível apenas no PHP7.

Ele verifica se a chave existe caso sim faz a atribuição com o respectivo valor ou do contrário o valor padrão.

```
$idade = $arr['idade'] ?? 99;
```

Comment: Como assim Post direto? Sou meio novato e sempre aprendi dessa maneira que está na pergunta, e sim eu preciso se o campo for digitado se não, não tenho a necessidade de ficar com uma variável vazia

Comment: @SauldaSilvaRolim dependendo do caso pode passar para frente (funções/chamar) o `$_POST` direto não precisa criar uma nova variável. Ex: `validaCPF($_POST['cpf']);` ou ainda como: `validaCPF(isset($_POST['cpf']) ? $_POST['cpf'] : 'valor padrão');`

Answer (score 2):

Algo realmente prático e recomendado é fazer o uso de operadores ternários junto com as funções `isset` e `empty` como na resposta do @rray, para evitar que a leitura de índices inexistentes.

Algo que também gosto de usar quando preciso de variáveis com o mesmo nome do índice atribuído no formulário *(ou mesmo por causa de formulários extensos)*, e ao mesmo tempo evitar erros como este *(undefined index)* é iterando a variável `$_POST` por inteira e excluir os valores de que não preciso.

```
# valores em $_POST, provenientes do formulário
Array ( [nome] => edilson [apelido] => samuel [email] => [enviar] => enviar )

if(isset($_POST)){
    foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $input)
    {
        switch($input):
            case 'enviar':
            case 'outro':
                unset($_POST[$input]);
                continue;
            default:
                ${$input} = $_POST[$input];
                print "${$input} : $input <br>";
                break;
        endswitch;  

    }
    if($email){
        print "<br>email definido<br>";
    } else {
        print "<br>email não definido<br>";
    }
}
```

Em caso de filtros, aplica-se directamente à `${$input}`, o que resulta em algo assim:

```
${$input} = validar($_POST[$input]);
```